# How do I do the SQL equivalent of "DISTINCT" in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

I have a bunch of MP3 metadata in CouchDB. I want to return every album that is in the MP3 metadata, but no duplicates.

A typical document looks like this:

```js
{
   "_id": "005e16a055ba78589695c583fbcdf7e26064df98",
   "_rev": "2-87aa12c52ee0a406084b09eca6116804",
   "name": "Fifty-Fifty Clown",
   "number": 15,
   "artist": "Cocteau Twins",
   "bitrate": 320,
   "album": "Stars and Topsoil: A Collection (1982-1990)",
   "path": "Cocteau Twins/Stars and Topsoil: A Collection (1982-1990)/15 - Fifty-Fifty Clown.mp3",
   "year": 0,
   "genre": "Shoegaze"
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe your map/reduce would look something like:

```
function map(doc) {
    emit(doc.album, null);
}

function reduce(key, values) {
    return null;
}
```

Remember to query with the extra parameter `group=true`

Comment: Could you please explain where the magic is in returning unique values?

Comment: Sure. Remember that the `map` function accepts one document and calls `emit` on `(key, value)` pairs. Because we only care about the album - nothing else - we only emit that. Then, for each *distinct* key, CouchDB will call `reduce(key, values)` and use that as the result of your query (again, we simply return `null` from `reduce` because we don't care about the value).

Comment: I think you'll also want to run this query with group=true

Comment: Excellent. Worked beautifully. Thanks for the explanation, David.

Comment: How would you instead return one object that contains one property that is a distinct sorted array of albums? I want this because it is less verbose (not containing so many null values).

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at [View Cookbook for SQL Jockeys'](http://books.couchdb.org/relax/reference/views-for-sql-jockeys) [*Get Unique Values*](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/cookbook.html#unique) section.

Comment: link is broken...
https://guide.couchdb.org/draft/cookbook.html