# How to replace Select distinct(empId) from Employee in Cloudant?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, nosql

I have a requirement to get only distinct Employee Ids from Employee table.
My emit is .. emit(doc.empId,1), will give me all employee ids ie duplicates one also. How i can achieve the same in cloudant. If i use the reduce on value will it return me all Distinct employee ids?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Reduce function to obtain the distinct employee Ids.

see duplicate question: [How do I do the SQL equivalent of "DISTINCT" in CouchDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534376/how-do-i-do-the-sql-equivalent-of-distinct-in-couchdb)

if you are not interested in the value it could be simply

Map function

```
function (doc) {
    emit(doc.empId, null);
}
```

Reduce function

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {
    return null;
}
```

however, if you need to return values you can try something like this

Map

```
function (doc) {
  emit([doc.empId, doc.joiningDate], {"companyId": doc.companyId, "dept": doc.dept});
}
```

Reduce

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
  return values[0];
}
```

however, you need to make sure the `values` argument in the Reduce function is an array of all the objects emitted in the Map function. therefore, you will need to determine how best to

> reduce to a single scalar value. That is, an integer; a string; or a
>   small, fixed-size list or object that includes an aggregated value (or
>   values) from the values argument.

from http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/cookbook.html

in my example, above i simply just took the first entry from `values` (i am assuming all the emitting values are identical).

Comment: Hi Barbosa Thanks for the answer but i need values , actually i need to get full document as in values like emit([doc.empId,doc.joiningDate],doc), (need to pass joining date as filter )i fear if above solution works or i just need to simply say return doc in reduce?, please correct me if i am wrong...please bear with me i am new to cloudant

Comment: @MayankMike not a problem. i no expert just trying to be helpful. we are all new at one time. i updated the answer to show an example of emitting values as well. you just need to keep in mind that in the Reduce you will need to somehow consolidate/condense/aggrigate/reduce the values into a single scalar value. depending on what the values are, you can determine how best to reduce.

Comment: Thanks Barbosa. Your solution works for me, but if the number of documents are less it works like creamy. but if i have more number of documents(say number of documents are:114655) i am getting error as {"error":"timeout","reason":"The request could not be processed in a reasonable amount of time."}.

Comment: The documents need to be indexed, which might take some time. I've seen this behavior if I tried to query a view right after it was created (and indexing is still in progress).