# How to retrieve distinct properties of documents

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb, pouchdb

In our CouchDB document database, we have documents with different "status" property values like this:

```
doc1: {status: "available"},
doc2: {status: "reserved"},
doc3: {status: "available"},
doc4: {status: "sold"},
doc5: {status: "available"},
doc6: {status: "destroyed"},
doc7: {status: "sold"}
[...]
```

Now, I would like to write a map-reduce function that returns all **distinct** status values that exist over all documents: `["available", "reserved", "sold", "destroyed"]`.

My approach was to begin writing a map function that returns only the "status" property of each document:

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.status) {
    emit(doc._id, doc.status);
  }
}
```

And now, I would like to compare **all map rows to each other** such that no status duplicates will be returned.

The [official CouchDB documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/intro.html?highlight=reduce#reduce-rereduce) seems to be very detailed and technical, but cannot really be projected to our use case, which does not have any nested structures like in blog posts but simply "flat objects" with a "status" property. Besides, our backend uses **PouchDB** as an adapter to connect to our remote CouchDB.

I discovered that when executing the reduce function below (which I implemented myself trying to understand what happens under the hood), some strange result will be returned.

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  var array = [];

  if(rereduce) {
    return values;
  } else {
    if(array.indexOf(values[0]) === -1) {
      array.push(values[0]);
    }
  }

  return array;
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "key": null,
      "value": "[reduce] [status] available,available,[status] sold,unknown,[status] available,[status] available,[status] available,reserved,available,[status] reserved,available,[status] available,[status] sold,reserved,[status] sold,sold,[status] available,available,[status] reserved,[status] reserved,[status] available,[status] reserved,available"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `reduce` step seems to be executed exactly once, while the `status` loops sometimes have only a single value, then two or three values, without a recognizable logic or pattern.

Could somebody please explain to me the following:

1. How to retrieve an array with all distinct status values
2. What is the logic (or workflow) of the `reduce` function of CouchDB? Why do `status` rows have an arbitrary number of status values?

Comment: Are you sure about the rereduce condition? I think you should negate this.

Comment: You should append (push) in case of rereduce.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534376/how-do-i-do-the-sql-equivalent-of-distinct-in-couchdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @chrisinmtown's comment I was able to implement the distinct retrieval of status values using the following functions:

```
function map(doc) {
  if(doc.status) {
    emit(doc.status, null);
  }
}
```

```
function reduce(key, values) {
  return null;
}
```

It is important to send the query parameter `group = true` as well, otherwise the result will be empty:

```
// PouchDB request
return this.database.query('general/all-status', { group: true }).pipe(
  map((response: PouchDB.Query.Response<any>) => response.rows.map((row: any) => row.key))
);
```

See also the [official PouchDB documentation](https://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html) for further information how to use views and queries.

Comment: Cool. Please show how you send the query parameter group = true, that will help the next person also.

Comment: So, uh, are you using *Couch* or *Pouch* database?

Comment: I use a CouchDB instance as the remote database, but I also use PouchDB as a local adapter to connect to the remote DB from the NestJS backend. Thus, the request syntax is PouchDB conform while the design documents and view functions are stored in the remote CouchDB.